# How to make a recursive function that gets all data from a JSON file and automatically makes a SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, json, recursion

I want to make a recursive function that gets all the data from a JSON file. Then the recursive function automatically makes a SQL table with the data from the JSON file.

Can someone tell me how I need to do this?

The JSON file contains arrays, bools, strings etc...

The programming language is c#.

Comment: Where does the recursion come in to the requirement?

Comment: could u plz share your json file and why u need recursion function?

Comment: @Adamg G It needs to loop in the json file and automatically makes a sql table.

Comment: The use of recursion implies that you expect the JSON to have a tree-like structure - but this doesn't fit well with a SQL table. Does the function need to create extra tables for each level of the JSON?

Comment: @ershoaib its just a json file with data and arrays.

Comment: what is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: JSON is for hierarchical data and SQL is for tabular data; it is not at all clear how you want to map between the two. Start much smaller. Can you solve the problem for a single JSON object with no child objects or arrays? That is logically a single row in a database table. **Show us how you would solve that simpler problem**. If you cannot solve the much simpler problem then you will never solve the much harder version!

Comment: @RobinBennett  yes.

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati I use the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: This question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: A loop isn't usually recursive. Think about your file system with folders within folders within folders to an arbitrary depth, where you may want to do something to each file in the folder, or submit any subfolder to the same method. That is recursion. You seem to be rather after something that iterates over the array.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later OPENJSON might help you. I added the anwer.

Comment: I agree with @EricLippert, I suggest to pay more attention to that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OPENJSON()` in SQL Server:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)

set @json='{...}'; --Your JSON value here

select
    *
from
    openjson(@json);
```

then insert the result into a table.

Comment: But what if the target database is not SQL Server at all? or The target database Is SQL Server, but a version lower than 2016?

Comment: you are right.i forgot to ask the dbms.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, OPENJSON might help you.